# Clicking Cart button is returning null value in Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a selenium script in python for an e-commerce web site. After selecting the products and adding them into cart, when i click on cart button for further process and to check out my cart value all of sudden become 0 to 1. Below is my simple script doing basic clicking and scrolling

One more think I am mentioning that if I am debugging one by one command it is working fine. Below are my step by steps screen shots attached from the script. 
[image: Image when I click on add to cart button]

[image: After clicking on cart icon]

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# declare variable to store the URL to be visited
base_url="https://testsite.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
#function of our 'driver' object.
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #10 is in seconds
driver.get(base_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("*****")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('arrow-icon').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
           
driver.find_element_by_link_text("FiveSeasons").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/article/section[1]/section/div/div[4]/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/article/section[1]/section/div/div[4]/div').click()

    #add to cart the product
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a/span/svg').click()


    #scrolling to view cart icon

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 0)")

    #clicking on cart icon to check out
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').click()
print("test")
```

Comment: Add some traceback or the website sample so that we can look up

Comment: @AvinashKarhana question is updated now with some samples and one more thing i have mentioned. This changing value of cart is not happening when I am debugging my code. It only occurring when I am running my script.

Comment: Doesn't helps until we get to see the website source code so that I can if the correct xpath and selector is used and possibly look at what goes wrong in betweeen. And I am not able to run this code locally like this, so either i need the source or local copy of this page you are working on

Comment: It would be great if you can provide us with a link to the website

Comment: my problem is solved now. I have inserted wait